# Regex removing all punctuation but leave decimal points and hyphenated words

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to make a regex that can remove all punctuations and whitespaces but keep the decimal points and hyphenated words. So far I have:

```
String doc = "THE SOCIAL IMPACT OF THE CHERNOBYL DISASTER BY DAVID R. MARPLES (ST. MARTIN'S PRESS: $35, CLOTH; $14.95, PAPER; 316 PP., ILLUSTRATED; 0-312-02432-0)";
String doc = doc.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z_0-9-]+", " ").toLowerCase();
```

It removes all the dots including the decimal points.

How can I make it differentiate if the dots are surrounding by characters or by numbers?

Expected output :

```
 the social impact of the chernobyl disaster by david r marples st martin s press 35 cloth 14.95 paper 316 pp illustrated 0-312-02432-0
```

Comment: can you provide example of what output you want?

Comment: If you remove `punctuations` and `whitespaces` then it won't affect hyphenated words at all. Do you mean to say you want to remove all hypens as well but keep those which are between words? This question is *unclear*.

Comment: Expected output: the social impact of the chernobyl disaster by david r marples st martin s 
press 35 cloth 14.95 paper 316 pp illustrated 0-312-02432-0

Comment: what I meant was words like "anti-communism" should be kept. The '-' character inbetween words should be distinctive from the character '-' alone. " a - b" for example, it should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-]|(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)|(?<!\w)-(?!\w)
```

> Update:

Added conditioning for hyphen `(?<!\w)-(?!\w)`

and replace by `" "`

Explanation:

1. `[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-]` included dot to your initial regex to not match it initially.
2. `(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)` here first `(?<!\d)` means if dot is not preceded by a
   number and the second `(?!\d)` means not followed by a number then match the dot for replacement

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dP2f02/4)

[Java Demo](http://ideone.com/586RHc)
Sample Source:

```
final String regex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-]|(?<!\\d)\\.(?!\\d)|(?<!\\w)-(?!\\w)";
final String string = "THE - . SOCIAL IMPACT OF THE CHERNOBYL DISASTER BY DAVID R. MARPLES "
        + "(ST. MARTIN'S PRESS: $35, CLOTH; $14.95, PAPER; 316 PP., ILLUSTRATED; 0-312-02432-0)\n\n\n";

String result=string.replaceAll(regex," ");
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: OP just mentioned `decimal points` so we can assume he meant decimal points points only.

Answer (score 0):

> remove all punctuations and whitespaces but keep the decimal points and hyphenated words

You can use an **optional capture group** to match decimal numbers and put it back in replacement using back-reference.

**Java Code:**

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("(\\.\\d+|\\w+(?:-\\w+)+)?[\\s\\p{P}]+", "$1 "));
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JpiHYi/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(` - Start capturing group

  - `\\.\\d+` - Match a DOT followed by digit
  - `|` - OR
  - `\\w+(?:-\\w+)+` - Match hyphenated words
- `)?` - End *optional* capturing group due to `?` after the group
- `[\\s\\p{P}]+` - Match 1 or more whitespace or punctuation character

**Replacement** string is: `"$1 "` that means back-reference of optional group #1 followed by a single space.